# Amazon Linux stack installing Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, passenger

I'm trying to install Phusion Passenger to launch a RoR app on an AWS stack with Amazon Linux 64 bit.

When Passenger checks for required software I'm getting the following error:

```
Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
```

I tried several options:

```
sudo yum install libssl-dev
sudo yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

But I always get something like:

```
No package libcurl4-openssl-dev available.
```

Do you know if it's possible to install Curl SSH headers in this stack?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you try libcurl-devel & openssl-devel

Comment: libcurl-devel Works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using the Amazon Linux distribution the packages you're looking for are `openssl-devel` and `libcurl-devel`

You can install them by running

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel openssl-devel
```

Hope this helps